# global variable in javascript used in a ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared a global variable `var idCategories= new Array();` in my `file.js`
I use it in this function

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://my_site/api/categories?ws_key=" 
             + ws_key  
             + "&PHP_AUTH_USER=" + PHP_AUTH_USER,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
    function parseXml(xml) {
        var i = 0;
        $(xml).find("category").each(function () {
            idCategories[i] = $(this).attr('id');
            // length increments at each iteration
            alert("length=" + idCategories.length);                 
            i = i + 1;
        });
    }
    alert("length=" + idCategories.length); //returns 0
}
```

in the function `parseXml(xml)` the array length is well incremented but outside of this function length = 0! so that I can't use the array `idCategories` in another function!

Comment: Can you post the entire example, including the global variable declaration?  Or create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.ajay is by default asynchronus function! That means thet when it starts to execute it does not block application flow. you're alert statement executes before $.ajax success function. You have two solutions.

1. set asny parameter to false.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       async: false,
   ```

   ...
2. call alert in **parseXml** function.

I belive you're best bet is **async:false**, but correct way of doing it would be to advance script execution after **$.ajax** call is finished (execute next step in parsexml function).

Comment: don't use `async = false` its the same as `var wait = true;while(wait);` when ajax is done `wait` is set to `false`

Comment: BUT synchronous calls are bad since they lock up the browser.

Comment: Advance youre execution after async call is finished!

Comment: @elrado: this is exactly what I want, but this is also my problem!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the AJAX call is ASYNC.  So `parseXml` will most likely, if not always, be called after your alert is called.

Why not:

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://my_site/api/categories?ws_key=" 
             + ws_key  
             + "&PHP_AUTH_USER=" + PHP_AUTH_USER,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
    function parseXml(xml) {
        var i = 0;
        $(xml).find("category").each(function () {
            idCategories[i] = $(this).attr('id');
            // length increments at each iteration
            alert("length=" + idCategories.length);                 
            i = i + 1;
        });
        alert("length=" + idCategories.length); //returns 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to using object and array

```
function parseXml(xml) {var obj={};var a = [];
  $(xml).find("category").each(function(i)  {
obj["idCategory"]= $(this).attr('id');
a.push(obj);
alert("length="+a.length);// length increments at each iteration
       });
}
alert("length="+a.length);//returns 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question appears multiple times a day. You are making an asynchronous call, that alert line fires BEFORE the Ajax call is returned.

Comment: Read the value in the callback function where you do the processing.

Comment: But I want to use it in other function also!

Comment: You have to code your code to wait for it to update, welcome to the world of asynchronous coding. Callbacks are meant to handle this stuff. Look into http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asyncronous. Your `alert("length="+idCategories.length);` code is called before response is delivered.